# Checkbox submits "value" no matter what

Tags: forms, checkbox

The simplest things........

I have a form with two separate checkboxes.  There's other stuff too, but basically it's this.

```
<form>
  <label style="font-size: 20px; width: 120px">Option 1</span> <input type="checkbox" name="selection_1" id="selection_1" style="width: 25px" value="1"/></label>
  <label style="font-size: 20px; width: 120px">Option 2</span> <input type="checkbox" name="selection_2" id="selection_2" style="width: 25px" value="2"/></label>
</form>
```

Every time I submit the form, **both** checkboxes are submitted as if they're checked.  This happens even if neither or only one is selected.  `$_POST['selection_1']` is always ending up as 1 and `$_POST['selection_2']` is always ending up as 2.

What am I missing here?

Comment: gtilflm, just remove those stray end tags (</span>) and give it a try https://jsfiddle.net/7c5Lbfo2/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to the user to make a choice: either one value or the other.

In this case, you might want to look at radio buttons (these can act as a group --> only one of the values is selected), whilst checkboxes each work individually.

Comment: Actually, I want the user to choose either, both, or none.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a jquery problem deeper in the code of this stupid script I was using.  Please disregard.